# Table mutating when "after insert" trigger fired, i don't know what to do

Tags: plsql

I want to increment the **samenameamount** column in my table **employees**  after inserting the similar name

**I have a such trigger:**

```
    create or replace trigger countNumbEmp after insert on employees for each row
declare
    var_count_names number;--var for count same names 
begin
    select count(emp_name) into var_count_names from employees where emp_name = :new.emp_name;
    update employees set samenameamount = var_count_names where emp_name = :new.emp_name;
end;
```

**My table is**

```
 - Name           Null? Type         
-------------- ----- ------------ 
  EMP_ID               NUMBER       

  EMP_NAME             VARCHAR2(20) 

  SAMENAMEAMOUNT       NUMBER
```

**After inserting i get this message:**

```
 - Error report -
ORA-04091: table DASTAN.EMPLOYEES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "DASTAN.COUNTNUMBEMP", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DASTAN.COUNTNUMBEMP'
```

Comment: See this (last point): http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm : A trigger can not change a table that it has read from. This is the mutating table error issue.

Comment: What you can do however, is to put `PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;` in the declare section and then put a `commit;` just after the `UPDATE` statement, but mark my words - This is something that you must absolutely avoid having in a Trigger (that is a `commit` statement)!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brief list of things that you should not do in a trigger (source [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm) here, my personal favorite page):

- On insert triggers have no :OLD values.
- On delete triggers have no :NEW values.
- Triggers do not commit transactions. If a transaction is rolled back,
  the data changed by the trigger is also rolled back.
- Commits, rollbacks and save points are not allowed in the trigger
  body. A commit/rollback affects the entire transaction, it is all or
  none.
- Unhandled exceptions in the trigger will cause a rollback of the
  entire transaction, not just the trigger.
- If more than one trigger is defined on an event, the order in which
  they fire is not defined. If the triggers must fire in order, you
  must create one trigger that executes all the actions in the required
  order.
- A trigger can cause other events to execute triggers. A trigger can
  not change a table that it has read from. This is the mutating table
  error issue.

I am intentionally not pasting the last part of that link, because it mentions things like "how to commit in a trigger" etc., as it's a bad  practice, even though it IS in fact a workaround. If you can't avoid having that, however, there's something wrong with the design of the solution or the implementation and this needs to be solved first.

Cheers